# Android Studio IDE : Not showing project module structure

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ide

I have a weird issue. I have included few new modules, and android studio is not showing its folders and files structure in Android tab, although it was working fine earlier.

I can see that the folders and other build files are included in Project tab. What's wrong?

[image: Project Perspective]

[image: Android Perspective]

Comment: Maybe try syncing your gradle again...?

Comment: Hussein I tried all sync, restart, invalidate :(

Comment: You might try right clicking on RemoteMobile => Open Module Settings => under the modules check that they have the right dependencies. You can also check your project build.gradle to see if the modules depend on something. Maybe your dependencies have disappeared?.

Comment: Try out my answer. It happened to me and I solved it that way.